# Changing product price depending on node field in commerce node checkout

Tags: commerce

i am using `comerce_node_checkout` with `drupal_commerce`

I want to change product price depending on node field .

eg,

I have a field as `field_gender` if we select `male` then price will be `1000.00` or if we select `female` then it will be `500`.

Any help is most appriciable.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Wow, women go half price? Think I'll be wearing a dress to your website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh!!!!!!!!

**Power Of Rules**

```
 { "rules_update_amount_female" : {
    "LABEL" : "Update amount Female",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "Update amount" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [
      "rules",
      "commerce_line_item",
      "commerce_product_reference",
      "commerce_cart"
    ],
    "ON" : {
      "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" : [],
      "commerce_cart_product_prepare" : []
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ],
          "field" : "commerce_node_checkout_node"
        }
      },
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-node-checkout-node" ],
          "field" : "field_ap_gender"
        }
      },
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-node-checkout-node:field-ap-gender" ],
          "value" : "Female"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_amount" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "amount" : "500",
          "component_name" : "base_price",
          "round_mode" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```